# How bright was Scholz when is passed near the Sun 70,000 years ago?

Tags: star, solar-system, binary-star

I just read that a star called Scholz passed only 0.8 years-light away from us 70,000 years ago.  It is a red dwarf. I don´t know how bright it was in the night sky. Does someone know how bright it was?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question at this place:
http://astronomynow.com/2015/02/18/suns-close-encounter-with-scholzsstar/

Here is the answer:

> Currently, Scholz’s Star is a small, dim red dwarf in the
>   constellation of Monoceros, about 20 light-years away. However, at the
>   closest point in its flyby of the solar system, Scholz’s Star would
>   have been a 10th magnitude star — about 50 times fainter than can
>   normally be seen with the naked eye at night. It is magnetically
>   active, however, which can cause stars to “flare” and briefly become
>   thousands of times brighter. So it is possible that Scholz’s Star may
>   have been visible to the naked eye by our ancestors 70,000 years ago
>   for minutes or hours at a time during rare flaring events. The star is
>   part of a binary star system: a low-mass red dwarf star (with mass
>   about 8% that of the Sun) and a “brown dwarf” companion (with mass
>   about 6% that of the Sun). Brown dwarfs are considered “failed stars;”
>   their masses are too low to fuse hydrogen in their cores like a
>   “star,” but they are still much more massive than gas giant planets
>   like Jupiter.

Comment: This article concurs: http://www.space.com/28611-star-flew-through-solar-system.html